# How to swap words position in a line using bash?

Tags: ssh, sh, scp

I have a command saved in string.

```
 toserver="scp -q -i ssh_key1.pem outfile ec2-user@ec2-18-205-233-131.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user/outfile"
```

And, from the above I want to swap the file positions and create new variable.
I mean, like below.

```
fromserver="scp -q -i ssh_key1.pem ec2-user@ec2-18-205-233-131.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user/outfile outfile"
```

the outfile name won't change but the server address might change.
Please suggest how to do this.

Comment: Note that in general, storing commands as strings in shell is considered a Very Bad Idea. [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) discusses some of the common problems, and alternate approaches used to avoid them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ fromserver=$(printf '%s\n' "$toserver" | sed s'/\([^.]*\.[^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) \(.*\)/\1 \3 \2/')
$ echo "$fromserver"
scp -q -i ssh_key1.pem ec2-user@ec2-18-205-233-131.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user/outfile outfile
```

Comment: sorry, there is change in command, can you check once more I edited it.

Comment: @Jor-El Please check edit

Comment: this is working from terminal but when I keep it as part of gitlab pipeline, it is failing.

$ new_copy_command=$(sed s'/\(.*\) \([^@]*.*\) \(.*\)/\1 \3 \2/' <<< "$new_copy_command")
/bin/sh: eval: line 177: syntax error: unexpected redirection

Comment: @Jor-El What shell are you using? Try echoing the variable rather than redirecting it. `fromserver=$(echo "$toserver" | sed s'/\([^.]*\.[^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) \(.*\)/\1 \3 \2/')`

Comment: using sh,  /bin/sh: eval: line 179: syntax error: unexpected redirection

Comment: @Jor-El Please change your script to use the shebang `#!/bin/bash` The redirection `<<<` is a bash extension. If your image does not have bash, then please try the echo solution or `printf '%s\n'  "$toserver" | sed s'/\([^.]*\.[^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) \(.*\)/\1 \3 \2/'`

Comment: Thank you, the echo approach is working